Access Salesforce data via API as an external user
We have community users who access Salesforce data. We have various sharing and visibility mechanisms and the user is able to see only the data they need to view. This all works fine when that user logs into Experience Cloud.
What if that user needs to access their data in their own application? I thought about creating a connected app and sharing the client id and secret to the external app. I understand that I can specify Scope to API Access. But wouldn't the connected app access all records?
I would like to understand what is us the best way to expose the data via API to these external apps but only specific records

If you choose the oAuth flow where the security context is that of the user logging in, you'll be fine. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/build-a-connected-app-for-api-integration/implement-the-oauth-20-web-server-authentication-flow

The Connected App can be used to allow OAuth 2.0 authentication on a user-by-user basis, so all sharing is still applied as expected (unless you define your own REST API or Web Service and do not apply it).
